# How to make a selection of of wx.choice required before the next event?

Tags: wxpython

I need to make a field, specifically a `wx.choice` required to fill in before submitting the form (or clicking a submit button). I do not know a line of code that I should use.

The research led me to a `wx.validator` function. Is this correct?

I do not have the code available.

I expect that if the submit is pressed, and that particular `wx.choice` is not selected, then the user will receive an error/dialogue asking them to make a selection.

Comment: grammar, formatting

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler than that.
When you activate the Save/Submit code, check to see if a valid choice has been made.
e.g.

```
import wx
class My_Class(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,size=(510,300), *args, **kwargs)
        self.mychoices=["choose","choice 1","choice 2","choice 3"]
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.message = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, ("Make a Choice"),pos=(10,20))
        self.choose = wx.Choice(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, choices=self.mychoices,pos=(120,20),size=(80,30))
        self.save = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Save",pos=(120,50),size=(50,30))
        self.choose.SetSelection(0)
        self.save.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSave)
        self.Show()

    def OnSave(self,event):
        choice = self.choose.GetSelection()
        text = self.choose.GetString(choice)
        if choice < 1:
            wx.MessageBox('You have not made a choice - Save cancelled!', 'Error', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
            return
        else:
            wx.MessageBox('Your submission '+text+' as been activated!', 'Success', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = My_Class(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!!! The error message totally pops out. However, I want to not only check if the correct choice has been made but also cancel the next set of events followed if the choice is invalid. How would I do that?

Comment: @el.lewis Perhaps the easiest way would be to set a variable. Create a variable like `self.ValidChoice = False`, then when a valid choice is made `self.ValidChoice = True` after that check `self.ValidChoice` before allowing other relevant events, if it's False don't allow them to procede.